# How do I drop my fury weapon?

Tags: dead-island

I've seen weapons with weird names like "furyfists" and "furyknife". I think that they're the unique weapons each character class wields when they activate their fury. How do you get them outside of fury?

In Dead Island, there are four character classes, much like Borderlands. And much like Borderlands, they each have a unique (action) skill A.K.A. fury. When fury is activated, the character wields a unique weapon that's common to each individual character's fury.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have any empty spaces in your inventory, i.e. your inventory space number status should be like 12/12, and find a weapon chest or corpse with an item spawned in it. Activate fury, then hold your Use button (e.g., default "F" key) to switch out your fury weapon for the one in the vessel.
Here's what'll happen: The item in the vessel will remain there, you'll drop your fury weapon, and you'll switch to your next best weapon in the weapon wheel.

It's also possible to drop the fury weapon outright, without needing to switch it with a vessel item, but [I](https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/post/dead_island_solo_68.html)'ve never been able to do so myself. This is according to SDA's [TheVoid](https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/profile/TheVoid.html):

"You need to activate Fury and immediately after press the drop key. Spamming probably doesn't work because as with other keypresses in the game it just gets ignored. So just activate Fury and then drop, click + click." - https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/post/dead_island_solo_70.html

Comment: So what does dropping your fury weapon do, exactly?

Comment: Lets you use the fury weapon outside of fury.